# How to mock the http response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, nock

Trying to test my `http` request but which actually fetch from the server a data that can be updated every second. So, I use `nock` to mock requests and my request looks like:

```
nock('http://localhost:8080')
      .get('/api/getbalance')
      .reply(200, { body: balance });
```

Where balance is my data and it looks like:

```
{
    "account": {
        "name": "Jack Torrance",
        "iban": "HTB0001234567",
        "balance": 3133.56
    },
    "currency": "EURO",
    "debitsAndCredits": [
        {
            "from": "Wendy",
            "description": "Diner",
            "amount": 10.50,
            "date": "2016-01-10T09:20:00.000Z"
        },
```

But if on the server this data will update - I will receive another data than I wrote in my tests in front-end. What the way to solve my problem?

My test case:

```
import nock from 'nock';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import * as actions from './';
import * as types from '../constants';

const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);

describe('async actions', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    nock.cleanAll();
  });

  it('creates FETCH_BALANCE_SUCCEESS when fetching balance has been done', () => {
    const store = mockStore({});

    const balance = {
      account: {
        name: 'Jack Torrance',
        iban: 'HTB0001234567',
        balance: 3133.56,
      },
      currency: 'EURO',
      debitsAndCredits: [
        {
          from: 'Wendy',
          description: 'Diner',
          amount: 10.5,
          date: '2016-01-10T09:20:00.000Z',
        },
      ],
    };

    nock('http://localhost:8080')
      .get('/api/getbalance')
      .reply(200, { body: balance });

    const expectedActions = [
      { type: types.FETCH_BALANCE_REQUEST },
      { type: types.FETCH_BALANCE_SUCCEESS, balance },
    ];

    return store.dispatch(actions.fetchBalance()).then(() => {
      expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
    });
  });
});
```

**UPD:**

I test that the actions are fired  using this example http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html#async-action-creators.
The problem is here `expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);`.  After I do `actions.fetchBalance()` my `store.getActions()` not the same as `expectedActions` because balance on the server change.

And test expects to receive:

```
  [ { type: types.FETCH_BALANCE_REQUEST },
  { type: types.FETCH_BALANCE_SUCCEESS, {
  account: {
    name: 'Jack Torrance',
    iban: 'HTB0001234567',
    balance: 3133.56,
  },
  currency: 'EURO',
  debitsAndCredits: [
    {
      from: 'Wendy',
      description: 'Diner',
      amount: 10.5,
      date: '2016-01-10T09:20:00.000Z',
    },
  ],
} },
];
```

But because data on the server change I can receive another one data:

```
   [ { type: types.FETCH_BALANCE_REQUEST },
  { type: types.FETCH_BALANCE_SUCCEESS, {
      name: 'Jack Torrance',
      iban: 'HTB0001234567',
      balance: 128.89,
    },
    currency: 'EURO',
    debitsAndCredits: [
      {
        to: 'Billy',
        description: 'Breakfast',
        amount: 11.15,
        date: '2016-11-10T09:20:00.000Z',
      },
    ],
  }
} }
];
```

Comment: _“Where balance is my data and it looks like”_ - I only see you creating an empty object in your code, so where is that data actually coming from …?

Comment: Is what you want to mock that request every X seconds?

Comment: I am sorry, I mean if I say `const balance = 1` server can return `2` in one minute, another one minute it can be `2`

Comment: So, what's the problem with hardcoding it, even if it changes? Are you testing the balance amount or whether the actions are fired?

Comment: @Bwaxxlo i test that the  actions are fired and I do it using this example http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html#async-action-creators. but after I do `actions.fetchBalance()` my `store.getActions()` not the same as `expectedActions ` because balance on the server change

Comment: Why are other actions being fired leading to this balance change? Are you testing on a **live server**? If yes, then this is a bad idea. If you are running other parallel tests, this is also not a thing to do on unit tests. The best idea is to hardcode your server response for each balance request

Comment: @Bwaxxlo make sense now, thanks!